# ApI blueprint Date format

Tags: date, apiblueprint

I have problem understanding the following date formate from apiblueprint tutorial

```
2016-02-05T08:40:51.620Z
```

I now `2016` is the year `02` is the month `05` is the date and `08:40:51` is the time but I dont understand the last part `.620Z`.
Can some one explain it for me. I wanted to find out AM or PM of the time using javascript from the date using javascript and not sure whether the formate is 12 or 24 hours.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, API Blueprint doesn't require you to use any particular Date format; you are free to use whatever you want to.

The format used in the tutorial is the standard [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): `.620` is the number of miliseconds, and `Z` designates a [Zulu timezone](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z), meaning UTC.